# Не работает условие с преобразованием в oracle TO_NUMBER(substr(column,1,3)) between 900 and 999

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

Изначально столбец column имеет тип данных varchar(19) там содержаться разные номера (1000094384, 9008564566, 999765443, 6786543 итп). Мне нужно выбрать номера начинающиеся от 900 до 999 (900,901,902...998,999). Преобразую в number TO_NUMBER(substr(column,1,3)) between 900 and 999 но пишет ошибку неверное число, пробовал через >= <= тоже самое

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что `substr(column,1,3)` возвращает не число. Возможно там есть буквы. Если вам надо найти значения, которые начинаются на 9, то проще это решить условием `column like '9%' and length(column) >=3`

Comment: Исключение "Неверное число" произсодит когда поле содержит вперемешку числовые и нечисловые данные. Нужно привести данные строго к числовому виду, а только потом делать TO_NUMBER, либо использовать другие способы сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно использует удобную Oracle функцию `regexp_like()`. Этот метод не требует преобразования данных.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N1x8-Mnq)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID int, col VARCHAR2(19) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO tbl (ID, col) 
WITH rs AS ( 
    SELECT 1, '1000094384'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, '999765443'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, '6786543'      FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, '9008564566'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Junk'         FROM dual 
)
SELECT * FROM rs;

SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE regexp_like(col, '^9[0-9][0-9].?');
```

**Результат**

| ID | COL |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 999765443 |
| 4 | 9008564566 |

Answer (score 1):

`to_number` умеет возвращать число в случае ошибки, чтобы не генерировать ошибку для буквенных данных:

```
TO_NUMBER(substr(column,1,3) default 0 on conversion error) between 900 and 999
```